# Generate swagger file for code in aws lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create a swagger file during my maven build, so I could use it to generate an API on AWS API Gateway service. I managed to create a kind of controller class with swagger annotations, but to build a swagger file out of my java controller class I need to use some kind of [swagger-maven-plugin](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin), but it supports

> Supports SpringMvc & JAX-RS

That means it will also look for annotations of jax-rs and spring, but I don't use them at all, but I need them to get my swagger file generated.

I tried to create a controller class with swagger annotations only, it did create a swagger file, by with no endpoints. Once I added `@Path` from jax-rs to my controller class - all my endpoint were successfully generated.

Are there any ways to generate a swagger file without any dependencies to springmvc and jax-rs.